# Return row # using match on two different columns

Tags: excel, vba

How do I return the row # that matches two different columns?

Both columns have duplicate values, but there is one unique identifier if you combine both.

My current code:

```vb
rowchange2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match (txtid & "Annual Amount", ws.Range("C:C") & ws.Range("F:F"), 0)
```

I understand that regular Excel uses Boolean values to return the row, but from browsing Google and forums, I'm seeing that Evaluate may have to be used.

How do get Evaluate & Match to work?

Comment: That is an array formula in the worksheet and as such `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` which does not have an array version will not work.  The quickest method is to load the used range of the data into variant arrays and iterate those to find where it matches on both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Evaluate`

```vb
Dim m, txtid, ws As Worksheet

txtid = "test"
Set ws = ActiveSheet

m = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(""" & txtid & """&""Annual Amount"", C:C&F:F, 0)")

Debug.Print m  'error value if no match, or row# of match
```